# Can I add a label for the explanatory variable using stargazer package in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, mixed-models, stargazer

I am trying to produce a regression table using `stargazer` package in R, and I am mimicking the style of this reported table in a research article I found. I looped over the arguments of stargazer documents, and it seems that there is no argument where I can specify "Hearing Status" like the one in the reference figure. Did the authors adjust the table manually after the raw table produced by stargazer maybe?

[Reference Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN8xd.jpg)

Also, I am new to epidemiologic study and I am wondering how people produce regression table for their publication? I assume people usually use a combination of stargazer and later maunal adjustment in MS word?

Comment: Welcome Bruce, would be good if you could provide minimal data for your request.